# How to write try except for loading data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I'm pretty new to coding so I apologize for this being stupid question.  I'm writing a spark function that takes in a file path and file type and creates a dataframe.  If the input is invalid, I want to just print some sort of error message and return an empty dataframe.  Would I use try except?

```
def rdf(name, type):
   try:
      df=spark.read.format(type).load(name)
      return df
   except ____ as error:
      print(error)
      return "" #I want to return an empty RDD here, but I can't figure out how to make one
```

How do I know what goes in the ____?  I tried org.apache.spark.SparkException because that's the error I get when I pass in a .csv file as a parquet and it breaks but that isn't working

Comment: Why is that `org.apache.spark.SparkException` not working? what error do you get in the traceback? You could try a generic `except Exception as error` and see what actual error you get.

Comment: @RafaelBarros it's saying that, but some other bad inputs I put in are giving different exceptions.  Is there anything wrong with just using except Exception?

Comment: well it does hide the errors in your code and may be a problem during when debugging. Check his comment on my answer

Comment: to create an empty df we would need to know the schema you expect.

Comment: @RafaelBarros like the number of rows and columns? I'm sorry, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I do appreciate the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can catch multiple exceptions in the try-except block; for instance:

```
def rdf(name, type):
   try:
      df=spark.read.format(type).load(name)
      return df
   except (SparkException, TypeError) as error:
      print(error)
      return ""
```

You could replace or add errors to that tuple.

Using a `Exception` will potentially silence errors that are unrelated to your code (like a networking issue if name is an S3 path). That is probably something you want your program to not handle.

Comment: great point here to highlight the danger of just sticking with generic, non-specific exceptions!

Comment: Where do you import `SparkException` from?

Comment: Since Spark 3.5 we can import it from `pyspark.errors.PySparkException` [source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.errors.PySparkException.html). In previous  versions you will have to use the general broad `Exception`.

Comment: Within pytest we can also do `with pytest.raises(Exception, match="SparkException"):`

Answer (score 2):

Use `Exception` if you don't know what exception it might be:

```py
def rdf(name, type):
   try:
      df=spark.read.format(type).load(name)
      return df
   except Exception as error:
      print(error)
      return ""
```

> *WARNING: This is not good practice as it could silence errors that would be useful during debugging and troubleshooting.*
>   (Thanks to @RafaelBarros)

Comment: This is not good practice as it could silence errors that you want to catch. Silencing exceptions like this will make troubleshooting very complicated.

Comment: yes but @user13591820 asked for what to put as the exception and this is the answer; but I will put your warning in the answer :)